# When the apple store replaces a battery in a 13in retina MacBook Pro, do they replace the top case and keyboard/trackpad assembly too?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, battery

I ask because I have a key missing and my keyboard and would like them both fixed at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you bring it into a Apple store? If you did and asked I'm sure they would do it. If you sent it in, they don't have to do it, but maybe if you get a lucky the technician will do it.

Comment: I have not taken it to the apple store yet. I thought they might have to replace both at the same time because the battery is glued to the top case. I ask because it is cheaper to replace the battery than it is to replace the keyboard.

Comment: Go to the Apple Store. They will replace it at no charge.That is my buddies experience. They fixed it at the store for him